# Уменьшать div при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю сайт. Идея такова, что при прокрутке страницы верхнее меню уменьшается, но остается на экране. Сделал вот так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var s = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (s > 0) {
    $('#headmenu').css('background-color', 'rgba(43, 140, 169, 0.95)'); 
    $('#headmenu').animate({
      height: "-=20px"

    },{duration: 50, queue: false}); 

    } else if (s == 0) {
    $('#headmenu').animate({
      height: '32%'
    },{duration: 50, queue: false}); 
    $('#headmenu').css('background-color', 'transparent');
 }
});
```

Вроде все получилось, но на днях забрел на [этот сайт](http://www.kubsu.ru/), и там меню сделано красивее. Как сделать такое же врехнее меню, как на том сайте?

Comment: Какой именно эффект из верхнего меню вам не понятно как сделать?

Comment: Чтобы при прокрутке страницы оно уменьшалось НО до определенного размера

Comment: Сделайте sandbox https://jsfiddle.net/ со своей реализацией

Comment: Fiddle - это здорово, но [минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода должен находиться и в самом вопросе. Другое дело, что тут нечего воспроизводить, потому что весь вопрос сводится к _вот там есть, хочу у себя так же_. Стоит попробовать сделать меню _как на том сайте_ самому и затем обратиться за помощью с конкретным вопросом/проблемой.